git push not working from cron job...but works manually. ssh seems to be the problem
I have a cron job that executes every 10 mins in Ubuntu 24.04
This is the content of the script it executes:
cd /home/rogga/csdc-scoreboard
source csdcvenv/bin/activate
python addplayers.py
python main.py

# Change to your repository directory
cd /home/rogga/crawl_cosplay

# Add changes
git -C /home/rogga/crawl_cosplay add .

# Commit changes
git -C /home/rogga/crawl_cosplay commit -m "Automated commit"

# Push changes to GitHub
export SSH_AGENT_PID=`ps -a | grep ssh-agent | grep -o -e [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=`find /tmp/ -path '*keyring-*' -name '*ssh*' -print 2>/dev/null` 
git -C /home/rogga/crawl_cosplay push origin master

I got the 2 export lines from: git push not working inside a cron job but it isn't working with or without the export line. How do I fix this?

Does the script have any logs or anything to clarify why it isn't working?

1. "Isn't working*" is meaningless; what line causes problems? (use /bin/sh -x or set -x to debug); what is the problem? show us an error message. 2. Minor nit: why git -C after cd /home/rogga/crawl_cosplay? you're already there…

3. Are you sure find finds something? echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK ?

the output to just has:
[master 9094cc3] Automated commit```
I don't know where the error messages logs are located

@phd #3: the output is blank when running your echo command.

@RoGGa This means that SSH_AUTH_SOCK is empty so Git cannot connect to your ssh-agent. You need to find out where the socket resides. Most probably it's in /run/, not /tmp. Do not blindly copy code from the Net without adapting it to your case.

@phd #1: I'm almost a noob with the terminal. Do I add the /bin/sh -x line to my script?

@RoGGa You should already have #!/bin/sh as the 1st line in your script; append  -x. Or add set -x as the 1st command in the script.

@phd: We're making progress but my knowledge is too limited with the terminal. Honestly, I'm just trying to hack this based on what I goggle. Sorry :-/

I changed /tmp/ to '/run/' and ran the script manually and it asked me to enter the passphrase for the ssh key...so we're making great progress!!!
How/where do I add the passphrase to the script? ...and with what syntax

@RoGGa ssh-agent is exactly the server that stores your keys and from which ssh draw the key without passphrases. If ssh asks passphrase that means either you haven't run ssh-agent or didn't add the key to it. You need to learn how to do both: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Public_Key_Authentication

I found this: https://alvinabad.wordpress.com/2013/03/23/how-to-specify-an-ssh-key-file-with-the-git-command/
but it's a bit too advanced for my limited knowledge. :-/
